# How to display all records in crystal reports

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a problem on displaying records in crystal reports, I am making a report on displaying the personal information of an employee. I made a parameter for Employee ID in which you have to enter the Employee's ID to view his/her information and print it. But I don't have the option to choose all the employee in which I can print all the employees profile at once. What I wanted to happen is that when I am not entering any Employee ID from the text-box it will display all the Employee information or profile and I can just click the next button in the report viewer to see the other employee and when I Click print it will print all the employees information. Can you help me with this guys... 
Thank you in advance.
By the way I am using vb.net  and MySQL database for this project...

Answer (score 1):

In the created static parameter add one default value `All`.

if you want to select all then select that paramter and in record selection formula write below code.

```
if {?parameter} <> "ALL"
then table.employeeid = {?Parameter}
else table.employeeid=table.employeeid
```

Try like this

```
{view_dtr.dtr_date} in {?date_from} to {?date_to} and if {?emp_id} <> "ALL" then 
{view_dtr.employee_id} = tonumber({?emp_id} )
else 
{view_dtr.employee_id}={view_dtr.employee_id}
```

Comment: there is an error it says a number range is required and it points to 2nd {?parameter}. My parameter is in string type and when I change to number type the error points to the 1st {?parameter} and it says string is required. Can you please tell me how to fix this...

Comment: Parameter should be string type...can you post your formula

Comment: {view_dtr.dtr_date} in {?date_from} to {?date_to} and
if {?emp_id} <> "ALL"
then {view_dtr.employee_id} = {?emp_id}
else {view_dtr.employee_id}={view_dtr.employee_id}

Comment: do i need to make 2 parameters for id?

Comment: Edited my answer check and let me know

Comment: sorry sir I've been busy lately i haven't tried that code you last suggested can you show that to me again sir so i can try it with my report.

Comment: it still doesn't work. it says "The string is non-numeric"

Comment: i tried entering a string ALL but it displays all the records of all employees but the name of the employee is only one and only one page is displayed.

Comment: Is name of employee coming from different table?

Comment: Try outer join to that table and see the records displaying or not